# Some hr tags have gaps inside them while other doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, css, codepen

I have a [pen](https://codepen.io/Rahul_V7/pen/dejPLN?editors=0100), which is basically a *todo app*. The todo items are actually `li` elements which have **text**, `button` and a `hr`. Some of them are having `hr` with **spaces inside** them while some doesn't.

Image:
[image: Red-marked todo items have spaces]

HTML:

```js
const j = $;

j(() => {
  let validify = txt => {
    if (txt.length > 0) {
      j('#ctn').append(`<li class='td'>${txt}<button class='td-btn'>Dismiss</button><hr/></li>`);
    }

    j('.td-btn').on('mouseenter', function() {
      console.log('added');
      j(this)
        .parent()
        .addClass('del');
      console.log(j(this).parent().attr('class'))
    }).on('mouseleave', function() {
      console.log('removed')
      j(this)
        .parent()
        .removeClass('del');
    }).on('click', function() {
      j(this).parent().css('display', 'none');
    });

    j('#addtd').val('');
  }
  validify('');

  j('#btn').on('click', () => {
    validify(j('#addtd').val());
  });
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Lato;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3vh 7vw;
  background: #004D40;
}

#in-ctn {
  position: fixed;
  width: 86vw;
  height: 16vh;
  background: #388E3C;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 9px #272727;
  z-index: 2;
}

#btn {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  right: 7vh;
  top: 3vh;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  font: 500 8vh arial;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.25s all;
  background: #CDDC39;
}

#btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

#btn:active {
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

#addtd {
  position: absolute;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33);
  width: 50vw;
  height: 6vh;
  top: 5vh;
  left: 5vw;
  font: 500 14pt Lato;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

#addtd::placeholder {
  color: #FFF;
}

#ctn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 27vh;
  width: 86vw;
  background: #388E3C;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 9px #272727;
  padding: 3vh 5vw;
  z-index: 1;
}

li.td {
  font: 500 20pt Lato;
  list-style: none;
  color: #FFF;
}

button.td-btn {
  float: right;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background: #E53935;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  color: #FFF;
}

hr {
  border: 7px solid #9E9D24;
  padding: 0;
}

.del {
  color: #CDDC39 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




<div id='main'>
  <div id='in-ctn'>
    <button id='btn'>+</button>
    <input type='text' id='addtd' placeholder='Enter a new Todo' />
  </div>
  <div id='ctn'>
    <li class='td'>
      Code a Todo App
      <button class='td-btn'>Dismiss</button>
      <hr/>
    </li>
    <li class='td'>
      Style the Elements
      <button class='td-btn'>Dismiss</button>
      <hr/>
    </li>
    <li class='td'>
      Debug some problems
      <button class='td-btn'>Dismiss</button>
      <hr/>
    </li>
    <li class='td'>
      Go for a walk
      <button class='td-btn'>Dismiss</button>
      <hr/>
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone explain me why it is so?

Comment: Please post your code snippets here. Snippets from external links are discouraged in SO.

Comment: Are my eyes bad or I don't see what the problem is? The codepen looks fine to me.

Comment: @Rahul by default `<hr>` tag have some margin. `margin: 0` mention if it does not work then add your code snippet.

Comment: I don't se problem on Chrome - on what browser you see problem?

Comment: I notice it with a zoom of 90%. Is this your case?

Comment: @Vincent Nguyen, I posted the **image** also, and you can see there spaces. @Meraj Khan, I tried it earlier, and now I **edited** my post with the snippet. @Kamil Kielczewski, I am using `Chrome`. @Fabio, No, zoom isn't the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening due to CSS Sub pixel rendering.
When you zoom-in/out of the browser, the rescaled elements will have left over pixel values like 5.75px etc. The vendor decides how to deal with that.

In your case the easiest fix, at least in Chrome, is to cancel the border radius to 0px, instead set the height of the hr to double the border and give it a background color:

```
border: 0px solid #9E9D24;
padding: 0;
height: 14px;
background: #9E9D24;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this issue is browser related, since it works fine for most people. Possibly your browser has a default styling for `hr` elements. It is, however, nowadays bad practice to use a horizontal line for presentational terms. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr)

You would be fine by using a `border-bottom` on your `li` element. If you want to position the border lower than the default position, you can use `padding-bottom` on the `li` element. Your HTML structure also looks a lot more clear with this.

For example, changing the styling of your CSS selector `li.td` to the following could do the trick:

```
li.td {
  font: 500 20pt Lato;
  list-style: none;
  color: #CDDC39;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #9E9D24;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

In case you really need to use the `hr` element, you could attempt to remove all default margin since some browsers add a margin by default. For that, add the following styling to the element:

```
margin: 0
```

which would result into

```
hr {
  border: 7px solid #9E9D24;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the `border-bottom` css property!

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit your pen to fix the issue? When looking at your pen preview all `<hr>` tags are rendered without an empty space inside.

The only suggestion I have, is that in HTML `<hr>` doesn't need to be explicitly closed, unless you are using XHTML, then you need to properly close the tag `<hr />`. Since you are just writing HTML, I would go with the `<hr>`.