# Chrome <hr> element split in middle

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have an `<hr>` element with a border, in Firefox it displayed nicely but in chrome, it has a split in the middle, does anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

How it should display:
[image]

How Chrome displays is:
[image]

CSS Styling:

```
hr {
  width: 90vw;
  border: 0.15em solid white;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371645/some-hr-tags-have-gaps-inside-them-while-other-doesnt). I think this might help.

Answer (score 1):

Style only the top border to avoid 2 lines. The thickness of the top border is the height of the hr.

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
}
hr {
    width: 90vw;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 0.15em solid white;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Comment: that sadly did not help, just age it a different artefact, but see the comment on the question that fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use only `border-top`, not `border`(which creates a rectangle with a border on all sides, as you can see it in Chrome). If you need it thicker, just change the thickness value.

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
}

hr {
  width: 90vw;
  border-top: 0.15em solid white;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<hr />
```

Comment: that sadly did not help, just age it a different artefact, but see the comment on the question that fixed it, thanks

Answer (score -1):

try giving border-radius,

````
    width: 90vw;
    border: 0.15em solid black;
    margin-top: 1em;
    border-radius: 2px
 }```
hope this will solve your query.
````